# Uncaught couldn't find jQuery UI at window.jQuery.ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, visualization, rickshaw

Rickshaw Example I am working with:
http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html

This example works wonderfully as an example, but once I begin incorporating live streaming data, I begin running into issues. For example, the following error appears. I should also mention, that I have moved the Rickshaw page from my windows machine to a linux server, in case there are dependencies that may be missing?

```
Uncaught couldn't find jQuery UI at window.jQuery.ui
Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Order @ rickshaw.min.js:2
(anonymous function) @ sensorDataDashboard.html:272
n.Callbacks.j @ jquery.js:3094
n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3206
x @ jquery.js:8259
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b @ jquery.js:8600
```

The associated line 272 within my sensorDataDashboard follows:

```
var order = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Order( {             // Enable real time reordering of series by user
            graph: graph,
            legend: legend
        } );
```

And I have included:

```
<script src="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css">
```

Digging into "Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Order":

```
if (typeof window.jQuery.ui == 'undefined') {
        throw "couldn't find jQuery UI at window.jQuery.ui";
    }
```

So, it appears that "typeof window.jQuery.ui == 'undefined'". I'm new to jQuery-UI however, so I'm not sure what this implies.

If there is any additional information I could provide to help nail down where this error comes from, that would be great! I haven't found others online with this error code in my searches.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, I did end up fixing the problem. I have a fully operational visualization with live streaming data. I had to make a large number of modifications and additions to the code in order to get it to work. If you have specific questions, I might be able to guide you as well. What are you trying to accomplish?